Can I travel to the UK with a child accompanied visa without the adult named on my visa but with the consent from that adult to another adult?
I am 17 years old and I have a UK child accompanied visa with my father's name written on it, saying that it is only valid if accompanied by my father.
But I am in the IMO team, which will take place this year in Bath, so I need to travel with my team and team leader to the UK without my father. Is it possible for me to get a consent form from my father that he authorizes my team leader to be the adult accompanying me? Will customs accept this?

You could consider applying for a UK visa even if under 18. See conditions etc here: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/if-youre-under-18

No. The conditions on your visa are what they are. I would also expect you'll be unable to board your flight to the UK with this condition and without your father coming with you. Note that it is not permitted for your father to accompany you to the gate and then leave you to travel to the UK alone or with another adult.

In cases where the accompanying adult has travelled with the child but remains airside and does not accompany the child into the UK, the terms of the visa will not be met. Further enquiries must be made of the child and of the accompanying adult, if the latter can be found. In such cases it may be appropriate to refuse the child entry.

So you'll need to apply for a new visa. You can state multiple adults on the new application as being permitted to accompany you (eg, both the team leader and your father, in case you have future UK travel planned).

From how the IMO operates, I suspect the team leader may travel early, and it is more likely (though not certain) that the deputy team leader will be travelling with the young team members.

@Henry: The obvious solution is to list every responsible adult who reasonably could end up traveling with the children. The only case where that runs into problems is if somebody decides it's a good idea to have the children fly as unaccompanied minors - but I would hope they would discuss that with the parents well in advance.
